# Trying to render different templates on the same route using express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have 2 buttons. When I click on the red button a red div is displayed and when I click on the blue button a blue div is displayed. I know this might not make sense but what I'm trying to do is use ajax so that when the buttons are clicked the server will know which div to output with specific appropriate data. Here is something I tried to do.

script js : the AJAX

```
$(function(){
    $("#red").hide();
    $("#displayRed").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/",
            context : $("#red"),
            data : {redClicked: true},
            success: function(data){
                $(this).show()
                $("#blue").hide()
                console.log(this)
            }
        })
    })

    $("#displayBlue").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/",
            data:{blueClicked : true},
            success : function(data){
                $("#blue").show();
                $("#red").hide();
            }
        })
    })
})
```

app.js :: trying to conditionally output a template

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var name;
var age;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set("view engine", "jade")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.query)
    if(req.query.redClicked == true){
        console.log("Red clicked")
        req.query.redClicked = false
        res.render("red.jade", //red data//)
    }
    else if(req.query.blueClicked == true){
        console.log("blue clicked")
        req.query.blueClicked = false
        res.render("blue.jade"// blue data//);
    }
    else{
        console.log("nothing clicked")
        res.render("2buttons.jade")
    }


})


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on 3000")
})
```

OK Here's a problem: **I get consoled "nothing clicked"** every time I click a button so I guess the other conditions aren't true. How can I do something like the way I want similar to my code?

red.jade:

```
html
head
    script(src="jquery.js")
    script(src="twoButtons.js")
body
    h1 test
    button#displayBlue Blue
    button#displayRed Red


    div(style="background:red; width:400; height:400;")#red Red
```

blue.jade:

```
html
head
    script(src="jquery.js")
    script(src="twoButtons.js")
body
    h1 test
    button#displayBlue Blue
    button#displayRed Red


    div(style="background:blue; width:400; height:400;")#blue Blue
```

2Buttons.jade :: I guess this should come into play when the `req.query.redClicked == false` and the other one is false (problem I think they are always false) ::

```
html
head
    script(src="jquery.js")
    script(src="twoButtons.js")
body
    h1 test
    button#displayBlue Blue
    button#displayRed Red

    div(style="background:blue; width:400; height:400;")#blue Blue
    div(style="background:red; width:400; height:400;")#red Red
```

the divs are supposed  to represent the different section when the buttons are clicked. They will have different style and elements with appropriate data passed from the server. because of that I would like to use html or templates instead of making string to output with on success in AJAX. Does that make sence?

Comment: Your `$.ajax` requests are going to send the data in the query like `http://localhost:3000&redClicked=true`, and that's parsed into `{ redClicked: "true" }` on the server. It's a string, not a boolean. Try changing `req.query.redClicked == true` to this: `req.query.redClicked === "true"`

Comment: That helps me alot but now I have another problem. I get the proper consoles but it looks like my `2Buttons.jade` is the only one showing up. I could tell because I tried passing data to the other two inside the div with render and they are not showing up on lick. I did further research  and when I take both divs away in the `2Buttons.jade` no divs show up like it supposed to. and when I click a button I get an empty object in the console of the AJAX call and no div shows up on screen. any suggestions about that would be great